# Reducing arrays in switch-statement (AngularJS)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, multidimensional-array, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

Sorry for the superficial description in the title of this post but I will explain it better in this text. However, in my Ctrl I'm using a `switch`-statement what is large. a bit to large and I'm looking for a solution to minimize it or to make more flexible.

A short description how it works. Currently the view contains 6 checkboxes. All checkboxes have a method `choose(r.val)` in the ngClick directive. So, when the user does interact with a checkbox the `choose`-method invokes a switch-statement. Why? To check which checkbox is clicked. The corresponding case with the value gets executed. The array `$scope.tableOptions = [...]` get used from all checkboxes that means in the view is a ngRepeat directive defined to display the chosen table.

The code looks like as follows:

```
$scope.choose = function (value) {
   switch (value) {
      case 1:
          $scope.changeDate = function (selDate) {
              CrudService.getArticle(selDate).$promise.then(
                   function (response) {
                      $scope.repos = response;
                   },
                   function (err) {
                      $log.info('error:', err);
                   });
          }

          $scope.tableOptions = [
               { columnTitle: 'Datum' },
               { columnTitle: 'ArtNr' },
               { columnTitle: 'Description' },
               { columnTitle: 'Price' }
          ];

          $scope.rowOptions = [
               { rowTitle: 'datum' },
               { rowTitle: 'artnr' },
               { rowTitle: 'descr' },
               { rowTitle: 'price' }
          ];
          break;
      case 2:
          $scope.changeName = function (selName) {
               CrudService.getNames(selName).$promise.then(
                   function (response) {
                      $scope.repos = response;
                   },
                   function (err) {
                      $log.info('error:', err);
                   });
          }

          $scope.tableOptions = [
               { columnTitle: 'Datum' },
               { columnTitle: 'Firstname' },
               { columnTitle: 'Lastname' },
               { columnTitle: 'Address' },
               { columnTitle: 'Age' }
          ];

          $scope.rowOptions = [
               { rowTitle: 'Datum' },
               { rowTitle: 'fname' },
               { rowTitle: 'lname' },
               { rowTitle: 'address' },
               { rowTitle: 'age' }
          ];
          break;
      case 3:
          ... // and so on..
```

To better imagine it I have added the view of this example:

```
<div class="table-responsive">
   <table class="table table-bordered table-hover">
      <thead>
         <tr>
           <th ng-repeat="tblOpt in tableOptions">
              {{ tblOpt.columnTitle }}
           </th>
         </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
         <tr ng-repeat="r in repos">
           <td ng-repeat="row in rowOptions">
              {{ r[row.rowTitle] }}
           </td>
         </tr>
      </tbody>
   </table>
</div>
```

My idea was to nest the arrays to each other. But perhaps there is a better solution for this. How can I define the arrays smarter?

Comment: you can use ng-repeat="tblOpt in tableOptions[choose]", and uses tableOptions as [ [ ... fields ... ], [ ... ] ]

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this what your trying to get at exactly, but one way to simplify the code and make it more modular. Is to separate your function into three of four functions instead of one. for instance , you could have a function called build table options and one called build row options, this would make your code more flexible, modular and easier to test

here is an example, you could also factor out the data calling portion but wihtout seeing the rest of you code i can not give a good example

```
$scope.choose = function (value) {
   switch (value) {
      case 1:
          $scope.changeDate = function (selDate) {
              CrudService.getArticle(selDate).$promise.then(
                   function (response) {
                      $scope.repos = response;
                   },
                   function (err) {
                      $log.info('error:', err);
                   });
          }

           $scope.buildTableOptions(['Datum' ,  'ArtNr' , 'Description' , 'Price']);
           $scope.buildRowOptions([ 'datum','artnr' ,'descr' ,'price']);
          break;
      case 2:
          $scope.changeName = function (selName) {
               CrudService.getNames(selName).$promise.then(
                   function (response) {
                      $scope.repos = response;
                   },
                   function (err) {
                      $log.info('error:', err);
                   });
          }

          $scope.buildTableOptions(['Datum', 'Firstname', 'Lastname', 'Address', 'Age']);
          $scope.buildRowOptions(['Datum' , 'fname','lname','address','age']);
          break;

   } 


  $scope.buildOptions = function(type, names){
      var options = [];
      names.forEach(function(el){

          var obj = {}
          obj[type] = el;
          options.push(obj)   

      }); 

      return options;        

  };


  $scope.buildTableOptions = function(options){

    $scope.rowOptions = $scope.buildOptions('columnTitle', options)

  };

   $scope.buildRowOptions = function(options){

    $scope.rowOptions = $scope.buildOptions('rowTitle', options)

  };
```

Comment: nice answer  I will try it. Which code do you need to give a better solution?